# Pushing to a defined 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a defined arraylist as a field variable.

```
String[][] data = {{"Neil-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"}};
```

I want to add

```
{"Bob-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"}
```

I've tried using a list, then converting it to a string array, but that failed as there is no '2d' option.

Comment: eeeeeeeeeee I am not an expert but it is a 2D array. Am I wrong?

Comment: can you explain in detail properly.. You are asking for arraylist while you are using array[][] ?

Comment: `data` isn't big enough to hold anything else they way you've declared it. You probably want an `ArrayList` of `String[3]`.

Comment: you are using arrays not lists, arrays in java have fixed size, so you can't append anything to already initialized array

Comment: @Girl it is 2D but the declaration has nothing in the second dimension.

Comment: The way it is defined/initialized `data` will contain only 1 item and you can't change that unless you add everything in data at once. Your other options is either to define data first with a length of 2 or more or otherwise use an `ArrayList` which is flexible and you don't have to worry about length thing.

Comment: The question asks how to push to a 2d array. Does that mean like stack pushing? The new element is on the top (at the start) of the data structure? You then mention another question that wants to add the new array to any position in the current array. Is that the functionality you require?

Answer (score 3):

When you define your array:

```
String[][] data = {{"Neil-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"}};
```

You are creating a 2D array of Strings. However, arrays are statically sized, and since there's nothing in the second dimension, there's no memory available for it. If you just want these two specific records, you could do something like this:

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][3];

String[] input1 = {"Neil-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"};
String[] input2 = {"Bob-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"};

arr[0] = input1;
arr[1] = input2;
```

However, since it seems like you're going to want to add an arbitrary amount of records, you probably want to use something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{    
     public static void main(String []args)
     {           
        ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String[] input1 = {"Neil-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"};
        String[] input2 = {"Bob-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"};

        list.add(input1);
        list.add(input2);                    
     }
}
```

ArrayLists allow you to keep adding elements at run time. You can read the Oracle tutorials on Lists and ArrayLists [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: I can't, JTable doesn't take ArrayLists, it only takes 2d Strings.

Comment: If you need to make a TableModel out of this data it would've been nice to know that at the beginning. IIRC you can model a table using Vectors instead of ArrayLists. The principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know because you want use a 2d array, but Java is Object Oriented Language so why not use object?

So I think something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
     private String namePc;

     private String ipAddress;

     pricate String hardwareDescription;

     //getter and setter method
}
```

and the you can use:

```
List<MyClass> computers = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

MyClass pc = new MyClass();
pc.setNamePc("Name");
pc.setIpAddress("192.168.168.2");
```

and then `computers.add(pc);`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could use a `List<String[]>`, or even a `List<List<String>>`, but if you're wanting to stick with 2D String arrays, you could do something like this:

```
public static String[][] addNewArray( final String[][] baseArray, final String[] toAdd ) {
    //Define a new 2D array with size 1 bigger to accommodate the extra array.
    final String[][] newArray = new String[ (baseArray.length + 1) ][];

    //Copy across the data from the basearray
    for( int i = 0; i < baseArray.length; i++ ) {
        newArray[i] = baseArray[i];
    }
    //Add on the extra array
    newArray[baseArray.length] = toAdd;

    return newArray;
}
```

Of course this does not cater for the length of each of the individual arrays, but there is no indiciation that that is a concern for your problem.

Here is a quick demonstration. The following main method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String[][] data = {{"Neil-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"}};
    final String[] extraData = {"Bob-PC","127.0.0.1","Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2"};

    final String[][] newArray = addNewArray(data, extraData);
    for (final String[] strings : newArray) {
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(strings) );
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

> [Neil-PC, 127.0.0.1, Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2]
>
> [Bob-PC, 127.0.0.1, Xeon 1230v3 + 2gb DDR2]